# Why is my generated excel spreadsheet not being separated by headers?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am currently creating a table in angular using a SalesDataList object, I then generate a excel spreadsheet using this table. this all works however, I am trying to separate my excel spreadsheet cells by headers using commas.

I am expecting the headers and rows to be in different columns, however, they are all in a single column.

My code for downloading the spreadsheet:

```
downloadTable(salesDataList: any) {
    const csvData = this.convertToCSV(salesDataList);
    console.log(csvData); // Check the generated CSV data
    const blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8' });
  
    // For modern browsers
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = 'table_data.csv';
    link.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
  }  
  

  convertToCSV(data: any[]) {
    const headers = Object.keys(data[0]);
    const headerRow = headers.join(',');
    const dataRows = data.map(item => headers.map(header => item[header]).join(','));
    return `${headerRow}\n${dataRows.join('\n')}`;
  }
```